# Cascading synchronization with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, synchronization

I tried really hard to search for information about the issue, but nothing was relevant.
Any contribution will be appreciated.

```
DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
public synchronized void run() { b(); }
private void b() { ds.update(); }
public synchronized void c() { ds.update(); }
```

Suppose that the above code is implemented using a thread.
as you might notice, there is a DataStructure object which is being shared and accessed through synchronized methods, when only one synchronized method can be called at any given time (I am not mistaken. right?).
Is there any possibility that the DataStructure object will be accessed through the public methods in unsynchronized manner?

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you call `c()` from `run()`?

Comment: `b()` is a small fraction of what `run()` should do, that is the reason why the design looks like that.

Comment: so `b()` != `c()` ? Also, why don't you `synchronize (ds)`, since it's actually `ds` what you are trying to protect?

Comment: is there a while loop in your run()?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, but if the above is part of a `Runnable` or `Thread`, then no concurrency is possible with the given methods since you're synchronizing the entire `run()` method. Using threads is pretty pointless in that case.

I also don't see where the `DataStructure` would be shared between threads - looks like a separate one is created for each one. If it actually is shared, then access would not be synchronized because you synchronize on the `Runnable` or `Thread` rather than the shared object.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you please read the answer below you and see if you could help?

Comment: @JavaNewbie: I agree with Chii that we don't have enough information. And I suspect that what you're seeing is not a deadlock but the effect of synchronizing the run() method - that means if other threads call c(), they will block until that thread is finished execution. Now if you have two such threads calling c() on each other THAT would be a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, its very hard to tell. What is the class that those methods belong to? how are they invoked, and by what classes?

Concurrency problems are hard to diagnose, and harder if there isn't enough information.

What i assume you have are threads that execute the run() method above, and there are different threads that execute the c() method. The synchronization happens on the class that the above method resides, so there wouldn't be any problems (except slowness if lots of threads).

Comment: Your assumption is right, that is exactly how the methods are invoked. Strangely, somehow, I am getting a deadlock.

Comment: @JavaNewbie: use `jstack` and have a look at the stack traces for the threads involved in the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

If

1. There is no other public method apart from what you wrote here, that has access to ds, and
2. "the DataStructure object" you are talking on is the object instance in a specific object instance of your class (instead of ALL DataStructure objects)

then what you are expecting is correct. There shouldn't be any concurrent access to ds through public methods of your class.

Honestly I don't see anything special in your class that make it different from normal synchronized method example.